# I am unable to get mp4 from Agora Cloud Recording. React jS

Tags: reactjs, agora, agora-cloud-recording

I am trying to record my live stream with Agoa Cloud Recording. It keeps in aws bucket, however I need it to give me mp4 file format, but I get m3u8 format. how to fix ?

This is [doc](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/reference/rest-api/start#configurations-for-the-recorded-files)

This is my code

`async function startRecording(resourceId, channelName, token, uId) { try { const Authorization =`Basic ${ Buffer.from(`${ REACT_APP_AGORA_CUSTOMER_KEY }:${ REACT_APP_AGORA_CUSTOMER_SECRET }`).toString("base64") }`;

```
     const response = await axios.post(
        `${ REACT_APP_AGORA_API_URL }${ REACT_APP_AGORA_APP_ID }/cloud_recording/resourceid/${ resourceId }/mode/mix/start`,
        {
           cname: channelName,
           uid: uId,
           clientRequest: {
              token: '007eJxTYFis56zfwqsZ61umPjM+klfudPUJZdNf7vy3L8iaPj99eqYCg4GlhYVxkrmhaUpqkkmypVFiorG5uZFJqlmaWYqFqYnFpcqC1IZARoY7YscYGRkgEMTnZ8jNTC0uKcrXDXIJNzT1M2VgAADd+yDV',
              recordingConfig: {
                 maxIdleTime: 30,
                 audioProfile: 1,
                 subscribeVideoUids: [],
                 subscribeAudioUids: [],
                 streamTypes: 2,
                 streamMode: "original",
                 channelType: 0,
                 videoStreamType: 0,
                 subscribeUidGroup: 0,
              },
              recordingFileConfig: {
                 avFileType: ["hls", "mp4"],
              },
              storageConfig: {
                 vendor: 1,
                 region: 3,
                 bucket: REACT_APP_AWS_BUCKET,
                 secretKey: REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_KEY,
                 accessKey: REACT_APP_AWS_KEY,
                 fileNamePrefix: [
                    app.uuid,
                    "livestream",
                 ],
              },
           },
        },
        { headers: { Authorization, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
     );

     const options = {
        uid: uId,
        sid: response.data.sid,
        resourceId,
        channelName,
        token,
        uniqId: user.uuid,
     };

     localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(options));
  } catch (error) {
     console.error("Error in startRecording:", error);
  }
```

}
`

I cannot get mp4 from this request. and this is my stop request

`const realCallEnd = async () => { const Authorization =`Basic ${ Buffer.from(`${ REACT_APP_AGORA_CUSTOMER_KEY }:${ REACT_APP_AGORA_CUSTOMER_SECRET }`).toString("base64") }`; const resourceId = itemsInfo.resourceId; const sid = itemsInfo.sid; const url =` ${ REACT_APP_AGORA_API_URL }${ REACT_APP_AGORA_APP_ID }/cloud_recording/resourceid/${ resourceId }/sid/${ sid }/mode/mix/stop`;
const cname = itemsInfo.channelName;
const uid = itemsInfo.uid;
// sessionStorage.removeItem('timer');
// endLiveStream(dataInfo.id).then(r => r.status >= 200 && history.push('/')).catch(() => toast.error('an error occurred'));
// localStorage.removeItem('live_stream_token_name');

```
  try {
     await axios.post(
        url,
        {
           cname,
           uid,
           clientRequest: {
              async_stop: true,
           },
        },
        { headers: { Authorization, 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' } }
     );
  } catch (error) {
     console.error('Error stopping recording:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
  }
```

};
`

How to fix this issue ?

I am trying to get mp4 format with m3u8, but I only get m3u8 format.